# Application is force closing when trying to pass data using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have main activity which contains few radio buttons. Their is one button named config.
What I want to do is on clicking config new activity will start and selected radio button text will be displayed.
But when I click on config application is forced closing.I am not able to figure out the bug.
I have gone through following links to learn about intent
1) http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/07/passing-data-using-intent-object.html
2) http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/how-to-start-new-activity-using-intent.html
Here is the code for onclick from main activity:

```
configbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {            
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked on 'Config'...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(!mode.equals(""))
            {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.av.android.profiles.configActivity");
            Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
            myBundle.putString("promode",mode);
            i.putExtras(myBundle);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
             else
             {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select profile mode to config...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

         }});
```

Code for Second Activity :

```
public class configActivity extends Activity{


Bundle myBundle1 = new Bundle();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.config);
    String myName = null;       
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        myName = extras.getString("promode");
    }


    TextView tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);
    tvData.setText(myName);
    }}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActvity.this,configActivity.class);
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putString("promode",mode);
i.putExtras(myBundle);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Declare `configActivity` in manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name=".configActivity" />
```

and use `myName = extras.getString("promode");`

Comment: Thanks once again... It's working now... I have used this method first time I was looking at wrong bug...

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if(extras != null)
    {
        myName = extras.getString("promode");
    }
```

instead of

```
if(extras != null)
    {
        myName = extras.getString("Name");
    }
```

because you are passing `promode` as key not `Name`

Comment: Argh... that's dumb mistake. I have edited it though still no luck